# Svelte's reactivity with array operation

Tags: javascript, svelte-3

I'm studying svelte.

the tutorial states that responsiveness is based on assignment and consequently operations with array such as `array.push()` must have an assignment.

`array.push()` can be converted to `numbers = [...numbers, numbers.length + 1]` .

How to convert pop, shift, unshift, splice and other similar operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unshift is the easiest, just use the reverse construction of the push

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4]
arr = [0, ...arr]
```

Shift can be rewritten using array destructuring, taking the first element and then spreading the rest back into the array-

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4];
[first, ...arr] = arr;
```

For `pop` and `splice` there is not really a *shortcut* you can follow, but you can always just reassign after doing the operation:

```js
arr.pop()
arr = arr
```

Answer (score 2):

It's unfortunate that these methods (`pop` , `shift`, `unshift`, `push`) don't work, and that's because the system requires the usage of the assignment operator (`=`) to work properly.

You can use `slice` and `concat` to achieve most of the other methods.

```js
// pop
let arr = [1,2,3];
arr = arr.slice(0, -1);
console.log(arr);
```

```js
// shift
let arr = [1,2,3];
arr = arr.slice(1);
console.log(arr);
```

```js
// splice
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
// delete number 6 from the list at index 5
const index = 5;
arr = arr.slice(0, index).concat(arr.slice(index + 1));
console.log(arr);
```

```js
// push
let arr = [1,2,3];
arr = arr.concat([4]);
console.log(arr);
```

```js
// unshift
let arr = [1,2,3];
arr = [0].concat(arr);
console.log(arr);
```